What is that coloured cartoon movie from 1980s-90s with one-legged pete following a gentle lady cartoon maybe minnie on rail track?
My dad went to Adelaide back in 1991 and brought back some VHS tapes. 
One of these tapes had a cartoon I am looking for. It was a US production from between 1985 to 1991.
I remember probably a series of disney cartoons back to back in it with disney characters.  The scene I can remember from the one I am interested is Disney Pete (one-legged) was the villian in it and was following a lady cartoon maybe Minnie Mouse on a railway. 
Someone falls into the wet mud and Pete gets out of his engine to pick 'em up. The railway track were too loose, they were moving up and down with every single step Pete took. Pete picks someone up and they start to scream and continue the screaming.

Could it be Mr. Mouse takes a trip?
Leaving for vacation, Mickey Mouse and Pluto arrive at a train station in Burbank, California (home of Walt Disney Productions headquarters). They board a west-bound train, but are both immediately kicked off by the conductor, played by Pete, that dogs aren't allowed (side gag reveals Pluto's luggage to contain bones). Pete then rambles off the train's destinations and forces his watch to tell him when the train is ready to leave. When the watch does show its time for the train to go, Pete calls "All aboard!"
Mickey, at this point, decides to smuggle Pluto onboard by squeezing the dog inside his suitcase. At first, the handle breaks, making Mickey almost leave Pluto behind, but he recovers the suitcase and manages to make it aboard the caboose just as the train is leaving the platform. Later, Pluto barks, wanting to be let out. Mickey reminds him that he will be thrown off if Pete finds out that Pluto's on the train, so he takes Pluto out and unsquashes him. The freedom is only short lived, however, as Pete is coming through the train to collect tickets, forcing Mickey to squash Pluto back into position in the suitcase. After biting "OK" in Mickey's tickets, Pete sees Mickey's suitcase containing Pluto in the seat and forcefully throws it into an overhead baggage net. This causes Pluto to bark, making Pete suspicious.
You can see it here:




Thank you for you answer Jo1storm, but Mickey was not in that cartoon
